# cakephp condition with LIKE operator: how to handle multiple values

Tags: cakephp-1.3

Hi I'm trying to do a condition like this:

```
array("Curriculum.name LIKE" => $array,"Curriculum.surname LIKE" => $array,)
```

But cakephp output is the following:

```
WHERE ((`Curriculum`.`name` LIKE IN ('%jon%','%x%')) OR (`Curriculum`.`surname` LIKE IN ('%jon%','%x%'))
```

Any idea in how to achieve this?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
foreach ($array as $name) {
    $conditions['or'][] = array('Curriculum.name LIKE' => "%$name%");
    $conditions['or'][] = array('Curriculum.surname LIKE' => "%$name%");
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the question and for the awesome answer. Did help a lot :)